# Сгрупировать список кортежей по первому элементу кортежа

Tags: python, list, tuple

Уважаемые коллеги помогите разобраться с одной казалось бы тривиальной задачей.

Есть список кортежей

```
list_tuple = [('A','word1'),('A', 'word2'),('A', 'word3'),('B', 'word1'),('B','word2'),('B','word3'),('C', 'word1'),('C','word2')]
```

Как превратить такие данные в сгрупированный вид по первому элементу кортежа следующего вида:

```
group_list = [('A', ['word1', 'word2','word3']), ('B', ['word1', 'word2','word3']), ('C', ['word1', 'word2'])]
```

Помогите с алгоритмом. Желательно без `itertools` или `collections`
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
list_tuple = [('A','word1'),('A', 'word2'),('A', 'word3'),('B', 'word1'),('B','word2'),('B','word3'),('C', 'word1'),('C','word2')]
res = {}

for key, value in list_tuple:
    if key in res:
        res[key].append(value)
    else:
        res[key] = [value]
```

если надо чтобы получился список, а не словарь то в конце добавьте строку

```
res = list(res.items())
```

Comment: res = list(res.items())) лишняя скобка в конце

Comment: @Jack_oS спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2):

Нужен `dict`. Без него элементы не сгруппировать. А у `dict` есть метод `setdefault` хорошо подходящий для создания отсутствующих ключей:

```
list_tuple = [
    ('A', 'word1'),
    ('A', 'word2'),
    ('A', 'word3'),
    ('B', 'word1'),
    ('B', 'word2'),
    ('B', 'word3'),
    ('C', 'word1'),
    ('C', 'word2')
]

d = {}
for k, v in list_tuple:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

group_list = list(d.items())

print(group_list)
```

Результат:

```
[('A', ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']), ('B', ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']), ('C', ['word1', 'word2'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

вариант 1 (со словарем):

```
list_tuple = [('A','word1'),('A', 'word2'),('A', 'word3'),('B', 'word1'),('B','word2'),('B','word3'),('C', 'word1'),('C','word2')]

tmp = dict()

for obj in list_tuple:
    tmp[obj[0]] = (tmp[obj[0]] + [obj[1]]) if obj[0] in tmp else [obj[1]]

res = list(tmp.items())

print(res)
```

вариант 2 (без словаря, с множеством):

```
res = [(j, [l[1] for l in filter(lambda k: k[0] == j, list_tuple)]) for j in {i[0] for i in list_tuple}]
```

или

```
res = [(j, [l[1] for l in [k for k in list_tuple if k[0] == j]]) for j in {i[0] for i in list_tuple}]
```

но тут список неотсортированный по букве получается и его надо будет отсортировать тогда